# Is it safe to use the rubber duck?

Tags: discussion, fun, april-fools, quack-overflow

Four days ago, I read an [alarming article in Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41522-018-0050-9). It claims that

> Fungi were identified in 58% of all real bath toys

and rubber ducks are explicitly mentioned in the article as a potential source of microbiomes. Has the Stack Exchange rubber duck been thoroughly checked on bacteria and fungi, and is it safe to use?

Comment: As long as there is no mushroom cloud when you squeeze the Duck we should be fine ...

Comment: That specific rubber duck has anti-fungus module built into him.

Comment: Next time, expecting an environment friendly quackie..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends if you have any pets.

My cat almost choked on the duck. I finally removed it using the Heimlich, but the duck has been quiet since and the cat has become a vegan.

Comment: I am pretty sure this rubber duck is manufactured using only organic 
 plastics, and cage free polymers.    So it should be completely pet safe.  And you are reading it on the internet so you know it has to be true.

Comment: _@Toon_ :-O What on earth are you feeding your cat with nowadays?!?

Answer (score 7):

You merely shouldn't use a *rubber duck* in your bath tub, but in serious conversations (with yourself).

That's what they're purposed for, not swimming around you in your bubblebath!

Answer (score 5):

[This person](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/19305275) found the duck to be unhelpful, but since he was able to write a question afterward, I believe we have at least minimal evidence that it does not harm even poor question-askers.